# PHP application response time increases when application requests decrease

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, php

I've got a very powerful dedicated server, running a PHP 5.5.3, MySQL (Percona 5.6) SMF forum. It's running Ubuntu 13.10, it's a Xeon E3-1270 V2, 1TB disk space (0.7% full), 16GB DDR3 (15% used).

I'm monitoring it with NewRelic.

Response time when there are regular requests is much lower when there are fewer requests (at night).

New relic shows that the response time increases when activity decreases. Response time (Apache+PHP + MySQL) is typically 25ms, but goes to 50ms when activity decreases (the increase in response time is in PHP, database is consistently fast.

The issue hints at swapping to disk, (IMO), but I've double checked my swappiness is set very low and I've got 0 bytes swapped. Memory useage floats at around 15% of the total 16GB.

My questions are twofold; What could be causing this? What can I do, if anything, to prevent this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Sounds like this could likely be due to various caching layers being more effective with steady usage. MySQL, php (depending on configuration), and the OS all have their own caching systems.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. There's a 100% InnoDB buffer pool hit rate, but looking at the graphs, it's definitely not MySQL, as that responds consistently fast regardless. It's definitely Apache/PHP. PHP is using the now built in Opcode caching.

Comment: Can you elaborate on response time values? Is it average per request over some time period or what?

Comment: Hi, Yes, it's average response times for requests in given periods. This isn't my graph, just shows the graph I'm referring to. https://www.getpantheon.com/sites/default/files/NRAppServerResponse.png